# How to set value based on existing column value

Tags: r

i imported a csv file by using read.csv, i checked the data format is 'list' by using `mode()`.

The csv imported file has a column called 'condition' with value: used or new 
[image]

Then i need to add a new column called'Isnew', if the existing column 'condition' is used, then 'Isnew' is 0, otherwise 'Isnew' is 1,

how to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks! I find a way!!

Comment: Better off with `as.integer(dataTableName$Condition != "used")`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dataTableName$IsNew <- ifelse(dataTableName$Condition == "used", 0, 1)
```